# How to DRY up models in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, model

I have a few models that share much of the same code.  **Where is the correct place to put the common code for models in Rails 3?**  I've contemplated using initializers, however I'm just not firm on the best practice here.

Comment: I would think you would make a Module and put it in libs.  But you should probably give a specific example from your situation.

Comment: I don't think initializers are the right path -- they are code that is needed only to bootstrap the system, set configurations, etc.  `application.rb` (and its cousin `application_controller.rb`) are there and automatically included to make shared model (and controller) methods globally accessible.  But I agree with Ken and ck3g -- if you have general purpose utilities used in several contexts, `lib` is the place to put them.  One exception would be a true example of subclassing (e.g. Animals model, with Dog, Cat subclasses each implementing a `sound` method, or some such fiction :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put similar code into modules and then include it in your models. Modules can be placed in `lib/models/` for example.

Answer (score 2):

A lot of people would probably answer this by saying to put the code in a module and include it in those classes. That's not wrong and may be perfect for what you want to do, but it's not your only option. As Ken mentioned above, you should post a specific example because it really does depend on the context.

In my experience I've found that sometimes those shared methods actually belong in a separate class. Using a separate class instead of a module allows you to isolate it better, making it easier to test just those shared methods, without depending on the context of your model. I'm not saying one approach is better than the other, but it is an option and might get you thinking about your common methods in a new way.

Comment: In this case I can't post a particular example very easily.  The bottom line is that 4 models share much of the same functionality and code in terms of how they obtain data.  Essentially the app retrieves data from various places and I find myself more and more wanting to DRY it up so that I don't have to maintain similar or identical functionality across the models.  Ultimately these models are very specific to this app and when the overall app is abstracted out into sub apps, these models will always be specific to this particular sub app.

Answer (score 1):

IMO lib/ is really for libraries external to your application - almost like vendor/.  It also doesn't get autoloaded in development.

All application logic should really be in app/.  I sometimes use app/concerns for shared model/controller code - or why not even app/models/shared/?

As Beerlington says, it's also worth reconsidering whether a module is the right way to go. Consider what functionality you're trying to inject in and consider whether a separate class is more appropriate.

Comment: lib folder will not get auto-loaded even in other environments unless you add it to autoload_paths. I'm writing this since you specifically mentioned development in your answer.